# Add a style to the component using nth-child in Astro

Tags: css, sass, astrojs

I'm trying to add a margin only to the second child of `.box` element. As far as it works when I have standard `div` elements, it doesn't work when I have astro components there. I am using SASS to style.

Using astro components (margin to the second `<Card />` **is not** applied):

```
<div class="box">
    <Card title="card1" />
    <Card title="card2" />
    <Card title="card3" />
</div>
```

Using standard `div` elements (margin to the second `div` **is** applied):

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="card">card1</div>
    <div class="card">card2</div>
    <div class="card">card3</div>
</div>
```

CSS/SASS (I'm using `>` child combinator to specify the child):

```
.box {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    > :nth-child(2) {
        margin: 1em 0;
    }
}
```

Card component (HTML part):

```
<li class="card">{title}</li>
```

Is this some kind of CSS problem or astro and component specific?

I appreciate your help.

Comment: In which file have you placed the .box selector? What does this group of elements look like when you inspect the page?

Comment: @Alex I placed .box selector in index.astro file. When inspecting I am getting 3 <li> tags within a <div> element (using component approach), and 3 <div> tags in <div> element (using standard div's)

Comment: That should be fine, do you have a repo to check? It is probably something very small or maybe a version issue.

Comment: @Alex Here is the [code snippet](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/astro-m4jkmf) on code sandbox. Although I have the same exact code in my VS Code, I am getting a change in margin and background colour only on that standard div in .box, but not on a <Card /> component.

Comment: Everything looks ok there? The second child (Card) is getting that margin and background colour applied.